# Getting drop-down list's display value after updating its outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list which I build in the following manner :

```
var id = ...
var select_box = document.getElementById(id);
var options = '';
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
    options += '<option value=\"' + i + '\">' + i + '</option>'; 
}
var out = '<select id=\"' + id + '\">' + options + '</select>';
select_box.outerHTML = out;
```

Later in the code I try to get its display value

```
var selected_value = select_box.value;
```

The value I get is an empty string, why is that? How can I get the current value selected by the user?

Note : I build the select box in this manner for faster performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `select_box.outerHTML` to a new value, you are essentially replacing the whole element and hence `select_box` is left referring to a dropdown that is no longer shown on the page. Why not just modify its `innerHTML` instead?

```
var id = ...
var select_box = document.getElementById(id);
var options = '';
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
    options += '<option value=\"' + i + '\">' + i + '</option>'; 
}
select_box.innerHTML = options;
```

**Edit:** Apparently the above doesn't work in IE 9, but this should have wider browser support:

```
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
    select_box.appendChild(makeOption(i, i));
}

function makeOption(value, display) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", value);
    option.textContent = display;
    return option;
}
```

**Lastly, the simple option** is to *re*-select `select_box` after you overwrite it by adding this line to your original code:

```
select_box = document.getElementById(id);
```

but that just seems kind of pointless, and leaves you with two extra lines of code that serve no real purpose.

Comment: I can see the drop-down list on the page, I just can't get its selected value. If I place options into innerHTML then I see an empty list on the page.

Comment: Yes, you can see the dropdown list on the page, but it is a _different_ dropdown list from the one `select_box` is pointing to. Please show us the relevant portion of your HTML. The code I provided above works here: http://jsfiddle.net/g62dB/

Comment: I forgot to mention I use Internet Explorer 9. Your code in the jsfiddle works fine on Chrome and Firefox but in Internet Explorer I see an empty list also here.

Comment: I see. That's weird. I've added another version that should be IE9 compatible. http://jsfiddle.net/g62dB/2/

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I create drop-down lists with more than 4000 values, IE would build them very slow if I'll use the manner you used here. This is why I build them by updating the outer/innerHTML, it's making the building process' speed tolerable. Yet the problem is that if I update the outerHTML then later on I can't get the selected value out of the box and on the other hand updating the innerHTML is simply not working ...

Comment: Did you try the final suggestion above (just one extra line of code to your original script)?

Comment: Yes, I saw it just now. It's working now. Thank you !